# Outlook "conditional formatting" for meetings without other attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get meetings with other attendees (other than myself) to show up in a special color. My "own" meetings (without other attendees) are mostly just reminders, which I can easily move, but meetings with others require me to be somewhere & on time.

I rightclick calendar, choose "view settings", choose "conditional formatting", add a rule, choose a color, and click "condition".

I go to "advanced" and choose field > appointment > required attendees. I set the value as "is empty".

**It doesn't work as expected though: almost every appointment gets the color.**

- When I create a new appointment by selecting the calendar and typing
  something, it does not get the color.
- When I create a new appointment by doubleclicking the calendar, giving it a title, and saving, it does get the color.

Both appointments should be identical, though... very strange.

#### What is going wrong? How can I obtain the desired result?

Comment: New appointments don't have attendees, meetings do. The difference is if you add attendees or not. With that being said, I think the conditional format is not working as you expect because all meetings have at least one required attendee, the organizer. In those cases it is only you, Outlook sees that as the field is not empty. I've not figured out how to get it to do as you desire though.

Comment: **because all meetings have at least one required attendee, the organizer.** I thought about that, but that wouldn't explain the differences between creating in-calendar and doubleclick-calendar... both show me as organiser.

Answer (score 3):

Following is taken from [this blog,](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/811) pasted here for the record.  As CharlieRB mentions, appointments and meetings are different.  Sounds like you want to differentiate between the two.

To show all the Appointments in another color, create the following Conditional Formatting rule with 3 criteria:

1. Open the Conditional Formatting dialog
2. Outlook 2007
   View-> Current View-> Customize Current View…-> Automatic Formatting…
3. Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013
   tab View-> button View Settings-> Conditional Formatting…
4. Button: Add
5. Name your rule. For instance: Appointments
6. Select a color for your rule.
7. Press the Condition… button.
8. Select the Advanced tab.
9. Add the following criteria:

   - Field: Required Attendees
   - Condition: is (exactly)
   - Value:
10. Add the following criteria:

    - Field: Required Attendees
    - Condition: is empty
11. Add the following criteria:

    - Field: Organizer
    - Condition: is (exactly)
    - Value:
12. OK yourself out of all the open dialogs to return to the Calendar.

[image]

**Highlight Meetings rather than Appointments**

If you prefer to highlight the Meetings rather than the Appointments, do the following:

1. Change the color of the “Meetings (Optional Attendees only)” rule to
   a color of your liking.
2. Change the color of the “Appointments” rule
   to “None” or another color than you picked in step 1.
3. Create a new rule called “Meetings” without any criteria and place it under   the
   “Appointments” rule. Change the color for this rule to the same one
   that you picked in step 1 or another one but is at least different
   from the one you picked in step 2. Ignore the warning that you get
   when applying the rule. Conditional Formatting - Rules to highlight
   Meetings in a different color than Appointments

[image]

Mind the sorting order when adding rules.
The first one that applies colors the item.